# Reformatting JSON data into a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a set of JSON data that I'm trying to reformat to follow the javascript object model depicted on 'Timeline JS'.

This is the original JSON data which is stored in the variable "messages":

```
  {
   "user_id": 1,
   "subject_line": "Timeam feugiat invidunt",
   "type": "feugiat",
   "date": "2014,07,5",
   "message": "Butcher letterpress et tousled ea. Id do artisan"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "subject_line": "RE: Timeam feugiat invidunt",
    "type": "feugiat",
    "date": "2014,07,7",
    "message": "Butcher letterpress et tousled ea."   
  }
```

The JSON data would need to be reformatted into the following Javascript object syntax:

```
      timeline: {
        headline: "User 1", // messages.user_id 
        type: "default",
        text: "tousled",     
        date: [{
          startDate: "2014,07,5", //messages.date
          headline: "Timeam feugiat invidunt" //messages.subject_line
         },
         {
          startDate: "2014,07,7",
          headline: "RE: Timeam feugiat invidunt"
       }]
    }
```

This is my current code:

```
function(){
var messagesData;

// API data fetched and stored in 'messages'
messages.each(function(data){
  data = data.toJSON();
  messagesData = {
    timeline: {
      headline: "User " + data.user_id,
      type: "default",
      text: "tousled",     
      date: [{
        startDate: data.date,
        headline: data.subject_line
      }]
    }
  }
});  

}
```

However the data I'm getting back only returns one set of the 'date' array (which is the last date and subject line of the JSON data):

```
timeline: {
        headline: "User 1",
        type: "default",
        text: "tousled",     
        date: [{
          startDate: "2014,07,7",
          headline: "RE: Timeam feugiat invidunt"
         }]
    }
```

How would you loop through the JSON data so it'll return all given set of date and subject line?

Comment: `data = data.toJSON();` really works? That's odd, I would expect `toJSON()` to return a string. It's bad enough that developers confuse JS object literals with JSON, APIs don't have to encourage that. A JavaScript object is definitely not "JSON". Anyways, does messages only contain data from a single user? The reason why you only have one entry in `date` is because you are only defining it with a single entry and overwrite `messagesData` in each iteration.

Comment: I'm using Backbone.  To access a model's attributes, .toJSON would be required. toJSON() returns a copy of the attributes as an object

Comment: why can't something like `JSON.parse()` work for that purpose?

Comment: Ah, I guess I have to take that back. I forgot that `toJSON` is handled in a special way by `JSON.stringify`. So I should be mad at the ECMAScript people. *shakes fists*

Comment: @IvyLynx: The OP isn't actually working with JSON at all. They want to convert one array/object structure into another one.

Comment: @FelixKling fine but, aren't they using JSON functions to perform the translation? how is JSON irrelevant even if you're just using it as an intermediate state?

Comment: @IvyLynx: I guess the data is sent from the server as JSON, but when the client received it, it already converts it to an array/object via `JSON.parse`. For the problem the OP is trying to solve it is irrelevant where the data came from (e.g. as JSON), and converting the data to or from JSON wouldn't help in any way either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/twLsdzFZHmCwMvzwrux6?p=preview that should help you.

```
var messages = [{
   "user_id": 1,
   "subject_line": "Timeam feugiat invidunt",
   "type": "feugiat",
   "date": "2014,07,5",
   "message": "Butcher letterpress et tousled ea. Id do artisan"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "subject_line": "RE: Timeam feugiat invidunt",
    "type": "feugiat",
    "date": "2014,07,7",
    "message": "Butcher letterpress et tousled ea."   
  }];

var storyjs_data = {
    "timeline": {
      "headline": "User" + messages[0].user_id,
      "type": "default",
      "text": "tousled",
      "date": []
    }
  };

  $(messages).each(function(indx, message) {

    var _date = {
      "startDate": message.date,
      "headline": message.subject_line,

    };

    storyjs_data.timeline.date.push(_date);

  });
```

Comment: According to the question, `messages` already has an `.each.` method.